# Enviar valor da variável JS para o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, modal

Assim, eu tenho uma tabela onde exibo os dados do banco. Em cada linha há um botão, onde, adicionei um evento `onClick` , que chama uma função JS e abre um modal. Nessa função, ele passa o valor que está no atributo `var-data`:

```
<button data-var="<?php echo $cont; ?>" onClick="funcaoModal(this)" class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-atualizar">Atualizar</button>
```

Dentro da função:

```
 function funcaoModal(element) {
        var dataVar = $(element).attr('data-var')
        alert(dataVar)

    }
```

Eu consigo visualizar q  ele passa um valor certo do "$cont", que seria o index do meu Array de dados vindo do banco, pois eu quero fazer o seguinte, enviar para o `input ticket`, por exemplo, o valor "`<php $result[dataVar]['ticket]; ?>`", porém o problema é que não dá pra colocar a variável `dataVar` dentro do código PHP...

Daria certo se eu precisasse de somente 1 dado, pois aí eu colocaria já o codigo PHP no "data-var" do botão, passaria para a função, e enviaria para o modal. Mas eu preciso de várias informações, por isso eu estou enviando o numero do index, pois eu consigo puxar qualquer dado através dele, porém não consigo de forma alguma concatenar o JS no PHP, ou transformar tudo em JS.

Alguém tem uma solução?

Pode ser:
Atribuir vários valores ao botão, e quando clicado, ele envia todos para a função, que atribui a cada input do Modal
Ou uma forma de enviar somente o valor do index ao PHP, para que eu concatene a informação à chamada do array, daquela forma "<php $result[dataVar]['ticket]; ?>".

Alguém tem alguma solução?

Obs.
Fiz o seguinte teste:

```
function funcaoModal(element) {
        var dataVar = $(element).attr('data-var')
        $('#ticket').val("<"+"?php echo $result[2]['ticket']?>")
    }
```

Isso seta o valor no "value" do modal, mas por algum motivo fica assim:

[image: Ao invés de ficar o valor do "result", ele pega como uma string, porém, quando coloco o mesmo trecho direto no "value" do modal, ele volta a informação do "result"]

Ao invés de ficar o valor do "result", ele pega como uma string, porém, quando coloco o mesmo trecho direto no "value" do modal, ele volta a informação do "result"

Answer (score -2):

Embora não seja uma boa técnica, basta escrever dentro do JS com PHP. Não esqueça de que o PHP exige ";" no final de cada linha, diferentemente do JS.

```js
function funcaoModal(element) {
  var dataVar = $(element).attr('data-var')
  $('#ticket').val("<?php echo $result[2]['ticket']; ?>")
}
```

Comment: Então, acho que assim funciona, o problema é que no lugar do [2] eu preciso passar a variável dataVar, e ai ele não reconhece porque a variavel é do JS. E ai quando tentei quebrar, fechar a tag PHP depois do "[" ele não deixa também, a sintaxe php fica errada

Comment: **1)** Se não é uma "boa prática", o ideal não seria evitar fazê-la? **2)** Não basta escrever o PHP dentro do JS; isso pode funcionar no "arquivo html", pois é o arquivo PHP sendo processado no servidor e retornando um HTML, mas não é comum o PHP servir também os arquivos JS da aplicação - de fato nem há razão nisso, por isso o código PHP dentro do arquivo JS não só não será tratado pelo servidor como poderia, dependendo da situação, quebrar a sintaxe do JS. **3)** O PHP não **exige** o `;` no final da linha para a última expressão antes do `?>`, portanto o caractere é opcional aqui.